# Pegar valores dos inputs

Tags: php, javascript, input

Olá, gostaria de saber como pegar as informações de cada input do meu formulário, são inputs em html e outros gerados em JavaScript, quero enviar as informações por backend PHP para outra página.

Código: 


    Pedidos

```
<form method="POST" action="Exibe_Pedidos.php?valida=TRUE">
        Receita
        <input type="text" name="receita" placeholder="Ex: Pão de queijo">
    <table border=1 id="tabela">
    <tr><td colspan="6" style="text-align: center"><label>Pedidos:</label></td></tr>
    <tr>

    <div id="codProduto">
        <td>Cód. Produto:</td> 
        <td><input type="text" name="codProduto[]" placeholder="Cód. Produto"></td>
    </div>




    <div id="quantidade">
        <td><label>Quantidade:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="razao[]" placeholder="Quantidade"></td>
    </div>




    <div id="desconto">
        <td><label>Desconto:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="desconto[]" placeholder="Desconto"></td>
    </div>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Adicionar
  Cadastrar

```
</form> 


<script>

const adicionar = document.getElementById("adicionar");


const codProduto = document.getElementById("codProduto");
const quantidade = document.getElementById("quantidade");
const desconto = document.getElementById("desconto");


adicionar.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
let campo = document.createElement("input");
let campoQuantidade = document.createElement("input");
let campoDesconto = document.createElement("input");

campo.name = "";
campo.name = "";
campo.placeholder = "";

campoQuantidade.placeholder = "";
campoDesconto.placeholder = "Desconto";

var table = document.getElementById("tabela");
var row = table.insertRow(2);
row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "Cód. Produto:";
row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = `<input type="text" name="codProduto[]" placeholder="CodProduto"> `;
row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = "Quantidade";
row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = `<input type="text" name="razao[]" placeholder="Quantidade">`;
row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = "Desconto";
row.insertCell(5).innerHTML = `<input type="text" name="desconto[]" placeholder="Desconto">`;

});

</script>
```

Comment: Não faz sentido o uso de *let* e *const* no seu código. Como você tem uma constante com o input você só precisa acessar o valor com **codProduto.value**, por exemplo.

Comment: você quer pegar os valores no backend ou no javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Seu código está com um erro na `const adicionar`, pois ele não existe em seu HTML, isto deve ser verificado.

Focando na dúvida em si, para acessar o valor do `input` basta utilizar assim:

```
const codProduto = document.getElementById("codProduto").value;
const quantidade = document.getElementById("quantidade").value;
const razao = document.getElementById("razao").value;
const desconto = document.getElementById("desconto").value;
const receita = document.getElementById("receita").value;
```

Com o `value` você pega exatamente o valor do `input`, isto após ter alterado seu HTML e colcoado um ID para cada campo, com o mesmo nome que inseri no `getElementById`.

Também pode ser pego o valor com o `onChange`, onde ao alterar o valor do `input`, você conseguirá o valor dentro do `event.target.value`, onde o `event` é um parâmetro necessário da função chamada no `onChange`.

Segue abaixo um exemplo onde isto pode ser verificado. Note que removi o código que está com erro. Como está em um `<form>`, a função será chamada ao realizar um `submit`, ou seja, ao pressionar a tecla <kbd>enter</kbd>.

```js
function mostrar(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="Exibe_Pedidos.php?valida=TRUE">
        Receita
        <input type="text" id="receita" name="receita" placeholder="Ex: Pão de queijo">
    <table border=1 id="tabela">
    <tr><td colspan="6" style="text-align: center"><label>Pedidos:</label></td></tr>
    <tr>

    <div id="codProduto">
        <td>Cód. Produto:</td> 
        <td><input type="text" onchange="mostrar(event)" id="codProduto" name="codProduto[]" placeholder="Cód. Produto"></td>
    </div>




    <div id="quantidade">
        <td><label>Quantidade:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="razao" name="razao[]" placeholder="Quantidade"></td>
    </div>




    <div id="desconto">
        <td><label>Desconto:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="desconto" name="desconto[]" placeholder="Desconto"></td>
    </div>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: São inputs dinâmicos, como faria pra pegar o valor de cado um. Por exemplo se o usuário adicionar 10 input como pegar o valor de cada um, se disponibilizassem o codigo funcionando pra eu estudar agradeceria

Answer (score 0):

Pelo q eu entendi, vc quer pegar esses inputs no PHP, pra isso vc pode usar a variável $_POST pra obter os valores dos inputs a partir do name. Mais ou menos assim:

```
$input1 = $_POST["name_do_input"];
```

Lembrando que a string do índice tem q ser o name, não o id. Por isso na hora de criar esses inputs dinamicamente, vc tem q colocar names diferentes.

Logo após criar os campos, você pode nomeá-los, assim:

```
campo.name = "campo";
campoQuantidade.name = "quantidade";
campoDesconto.name = "desconto";
```

E pode pegar os valores no PHP:

```
$campo = $_POST["campo"];
$quantidade = $_POST["quantidade"];
$desconto = $_POST["desconto"];
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, mas como fazer isso tendo como base o meu código?Até o momento ele tá gerando os inputs, mas não nomeando cada um diferente

Comment: Logo depois de criar os campos você pode nomeá-los. Vou alterar minha resposta com um exemplo de código.

Comment: Aguardando o seu exemplo de código.

Comment: Já editei minha resposta com os exemplos.